# How to save data after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have working code that helps me create a to-do list. Everything works almost well. When I click on the "Enter" key, my page reloads. Similarly, after reloading the page, all created elements disappear. I have 2 questions: can you show how to save all created elements after reloading and how to avoid reloading by pressing on "Enter"? Thank you very much

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export function Creating_List () {

let [allTasks, setAllTasks] = useState([]);
let [input, setInput] = useState('');

let addTask = (myInput) => {
    if (myInput){
        let newTask = {
            id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,9),
            task: myInput,
            complete: false
        }
            setAllTasks([...allTasks, newTask])
    }
}

let taskDone = (id) => {
    setAllTasks([allTasks.filter((todo => todo.id !== id))])
}

let handleInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.currentTarget.value)
}

let submitTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTask(input);
    setInput('');
}

return (<div className='tasks'>
            <h1>Список задач {allTasks.length}</h1>

            <form>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={input}
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    placeholder="Нове завдання"
                />
            </form>
            <button onClick={submitTask} type="submit">Створити</button>

            <div>
            {allTasks.map(el => <div key={el.id}>{el.task} <button onClick={taskDone}>Виконано</button> </div>)}
            </div>

        </div>)
}
```

Comment: Put button `type="button"`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `<form>` to `<form onSubmit = {submitTask}>`, this will prevent the page from reloading on enter since you have `e.preventDefault()`. If you want data to persist after reloading, you can use `localStorage` or a database like `Firebase` or `MongoDB`, or you can create your own backend using `Node.js`.

Comment: Could you show how i can use `localStorage` here, please? Thank you

Comment: @Ronald Set a variable with `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` and then retrieve it with `localStorage.getItem('key')`